# Searching the Mass Lectionary for Readings from Particular Psalms

Tags: catholicism, mass, resource-request, psalms, lectionary

A Lectionary (in the Roman Rite) is composed of the readings and the responsorial Psalm assigned for each Mass of the year (Sundays, weekdays, and special occasions).

The Lectionary is arranged in two cycles, one for Sundays and one for weekdays.

The Sunday cycle is divided into three years, labeled: A, B, and C.

I would like to be be able to, say, be able to quickly determine when the next time a particular psalm, say, Psalm 1, will have excerpts from it read at Mass. I would also like to be able, if possible, to easily determine how many times exceprts from, say, Psalm 1, will be read at Mass over the complete cycle.

QUESTION: Is there an expedient way to search the Lectionary in order to find when an excerpt(s) from a particular Psalm will be read at Mass? Is there, perhaps, an online way of doing this without having to resort to a physical day-by-day search of the Lectionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*Novus Ordo* Mass's lectionary can be found on the USCCB website](https://bible.usccb.org/readings/calendar) or [The Catholic Lectionary Website](https://catholic-resources.org/Lectionary/) compiled by Felix Just, S.J., Ph.D.

Pre-Vatican II Mass ordos and calendars:

- [DivinumOfficium.com](https://www.divinumofficium.com/cgi-bin/horas/officium.pl)
- [1962Ordo.today](https://1962ordo.today/)

Comment: Thank you kindly for providing this answer. I'm glad to have the opportunity once again to acknowledge your answers now that my accounts seem to have been (finally) restored after being infiltrated by some strange phenomenon.